# Nock not intercepting http requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

I am currently using `node-fetch` and `nock` for an express server that sits on top of an angular project.

I have the following middleware that is making a call to an api:

```
export const middleware = async(response: any) => {
    try {
        const result = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
        return response.status(200).json(result);
    } catch(err) {
        logger.error({eventId: 'get-content', err});
        return response.status(500)
    }
}
```

and my test is as follows:

```
describe('API service', () => {
    let response, scope;
    beforeEach(() => {
        response = {
            status(s) { this.statusCode = s; return this; },
            json(result) { this.res = result; return this; },
        };
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        nock.restore();
    })

    it('should return a 200 response from successful call api', (done) => {
        scope = nock(url)
            .get(/.*/)
            .reply(200, {data: 'content'})

        middleware(response).then(data => {
            expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
            expect(response.data).toEqual('content');
            scope.isDone();
            done();
        })
    })
})
```

However, nock is not mocking the `data` response from the middleware function. Instead, I'd have to use `scope` to access its parameters.

**The middleware function acts as if nock never mocked its response. Why is this occurring?** Am I missing a configuration?

I am serving my tests using karma runner.

Answer (score 2):

> Nock works by overriding Node's http.request function. Also, it overrides http.ClientRequest too to cover for modules that use it directly.
>
> - https://github.com/nock/nock#how-does-it-work

Unfortunately it appears `fetch` does not make use of the `http.request` or `http.ClientRequest` meaning the requests are never intercepted by `nock`.

A better approach may be to mock `fetch` with a library such as [`fetch-mock`](http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/).

Comment: `node-fetch` (what OP asked) *does* use http.request: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/main/src/index.js#L65

Comment: For anyone information, an issue is opened about this: https://github.com/nock/nock/issues/2397

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same & it is working fine for me. Can you check the below piece of code & try.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const nock = require('nock');

describe('My Fetch POST Test with Nock', () => {
  it('should mock a POST fetch call using nock', async () => {
    // Set up the nock mock for the URL and the POST request
    const requestBody = { key: 'value' };
    const scope = nock('https://api.example.com')
      .post('/data', requestBody)
      .reply(201, { message: 'Created successfully' });

    // Perform the fetch call
    const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    const data = await response.json();

    // Ensure all expectations of the nock mock are satisfied
    scope.done();
  });
});
```

Comment: You are using `node-fetch`, which is a third-party library and not the native node fetch api: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/globals.html. The replacement is a possible workaround, but node-fetch and native API types are not perfectly compatible with each other.